# Does a Plug router need a match/dispatch pipeline?

Tags: elixir, plug

I have a Router module that forwards request to other routers. 
In this router I have a pipleline comprised of `plug(:match)` and `plug(:dispatch)`.

```ex
defmodule Example.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  forward("/check", to: Example.Route.Check)

  get("/", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "router"))
end
```

In this second module I have the same pipeline:

```ex
defmodule Example.Route.Check do
  use Plug.Router

  plug(:match)
  plug(:dispatch)

  get "/", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "ok")
end
```

---

The issue I see here is that I always seem to need `plug(:match)` and `plug(:dispatch)` in all `Plug` Routers. So I have the following questions:

1. Is this really necessary?
2. Do all routers need to have a pipeline in the same file they have the routes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, both of the plugs are always required:**

- The [`:match`](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/e9bc0f7cf94ec95189ca5876c2ff67649dce48d9/lib/plug/router.ex#L202-L204) plug is responsible for, well, *matching* the incoming request to one of the defined routes in the Router.
- The [`:dispatch`](https://github.com/elixir-plug/plug/blob/e9bc0f7cf94ec95189ca5876c2ff67649dce48d9/lib/plug/router.ex#L207-L210) plug is responsible for finally *processing* the request in the matched route.

---

The obvious question here would be:

> *Why not just do it automatically, since this needs to be done for every request?*

1. For starters, it's because [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) has a design philosophy of doing things *explicitly* instead of *implicitly*.
2. Second and more importantly, **plugs are executed in the order they are defined**. This gives the developer full control of how incoming requests are processed.

---

For example, you might want to check for an `Authorization` header before a route is matched and halt or continue the request from there. Or you might want to update the pageview count in a separate process, once a route is matched but before it's processed. Another common scenario is to [parse a JSON request](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Router.html#module-parameter-parsing) *after* a route is matched.

You could do all this and more by customizing the pipeline:

```ex
defmodule Example.Router do
  use Plug.Router

  plug(CheckRateLimit)
  plug(VerifyAuthHeader)
  plug(:match)
  plug(LogWebRequest)
  plug(Plug.Parsers, parsers: [:json], ...)
  plug(:dispatch)

  # ...
end
```

The ability to forward matched routes to other routers can make your web server much more sophisticated. For example, you could check the API rate limit in your base router, forward `/admin` routes to a separate `AuthorizedRouter` and put a custom `VerifyAuthHeader` plug there before those routes are matched.

Answer (score 2):

While the answer by @Sheharyar is absolutely correct, I would add that you might DRY by introducing your own helper macro:

```rb
defmodule Example.Route.Common do
  defmacro __using__(opts \\ []) do
    quote do
      use Plug.Router

      plug(:match)
      plug(:dispatch)
    end
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```rb
defmodule Example.Route.Check do
  use Example.Route.Common

  get "/", do: send_resp(conn, 200, "ok")
end
```

The `opts` parameter might be used to fine configure the plugs included.

[`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html#use/2).